# Why isn't errorlevel being reset after this wget call?

Tags: windows, cmd, wget

Here is my code:

```
wget url
if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (
    powershell.exe restart-service wampapache
    SET errorlevel= 0
    PING -n 41 127.0.0.1>nul
    wget url
    if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (
        THIS PART COMES UP EVEN THOUGH THE wget can access the url and apache is up
    )
)
```

It seems like the first errorlevel gets set and then the subsequent wget cant overwrite it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In batch files, each line or block of lines (code inside parenthesis) is parsed, executed and the process repeated for the next line/block. During the parse phase, all variable reads are removed, being replaced with the value in the variable **before** the code starts to execute. If a variable changes its value inside the line/block, this changed value can not be retrieved from inside the same line/block as the variable read operation does not exist.

The usual way to solve it is to use delayed expansion. When enabled, you can change (where needed) the syntax from %var% to !var!, indicating to the parser that the read operation must be delayed until the command that uses the value starts to execute.

```dos
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (
     ....
     wget url
     if !errorlevel! gtr 0 (
     )
    ....
)
```

In the first case, normal expansion can be used as the value of the variable has changed before the block is parsed. In the second case, the variable changes inside the block and to retrieve this changed value delayed expansion is used.

When the variable is `%errorlevel%`, you can change your syntax and use the usual `if errorlevel` syntax to check your result.

```dos
if errorlevel 1 (
    ....
)
```

It will evaluate to true for any errorlevel value equal or greater than the indicated one.

Another option is to use conditional execution operators `&&` (execute following code if the previous command has not raised errorlevel) and `||` (execute following code if the previous command has raised errorlevel)

```dos
wget url || echo failed
wget url && echo it works
wget url && (echo it works) || (echo failed)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful and useful information